# How to properly hide selected dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the bootstrap button drop downs (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) but need something lightweight. Basic functionality is more or less this:

- On clicking the link, corresponding dropdown div opens (works)
- On clicking another link, the previous dropdown closes as well as the css class is removed (works)
- On clicking on the link of the opened dropdown, close the dropdown (does not work (closes and reopens))
- On clicking anywhere in the body (so outside the link and dropdown), close the dropdown (does not work)

What should be the logic behind this?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fU2BZ/

Does the code below make sense?

```
$(document).click( function(){
    $('.dropdownbox').hide(0);
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
});

$('.dropdown').click( function(event){        
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
    $('.dropdownbox').hide();
    $(this).addClass('active').find('.dropdownbox').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Made some changes to your code, added some if else logic, seems to work.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fU2BZ/1/

Code:

```
$('.dropdown').click( function(event){        
event.stopPropagation();

if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
    $('.dropdownbox').hide();
} else {
    $('.dropdownbox').hide();
    $(this).addClass('active').find('.dropdownbox').slideToggle(200);
}
});
```

Comment: If you swap between dropdowns, the old ones keep the active class. Might want to fix that one up!

Comment: Thanks, quite it, there is a small bug however when you click on the area inside an opened dropdown, it causes it too close, which should not happen
.

Comment: I see I see, looking into it!

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close. I'd store a flag if it was visible (so that you don't double-up on the same code)

```
$('.dropdown').click( function(event){        
    event.stopPropagation();

    var active = false;

    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') )
        active = true;

    $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
    $('.dropdownbox').hide();

    if ( ! active )
        $(this).addClass('active').find('.dropdownbox').slideToggle(200);
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fU2BZ/4/

Comment: Thanks Christian, nice solution, however have the same bug as the answer above (when click inside the opened dropdown it closes it, which should only happen outside of the dropdown and it's link).

Answer (score 2):

Simple code to resolve your third issue:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('active').not(this).find('.dropdownbox').hide();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').find('.dropdownbox').slideToggle(200);
});
```

To resolve your last issue, do this:

```
$('.dropdownbox').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for solving the third issue. Regarding the fourth one; no, tried again but still not getting it to work..